# How many are the RgVedic Devatas or gods in number?

Tags: gods, rig-veda, brahman

We've heard of **33** crores of **Devatas**. We've heard of armed conflict between Devatas and Asuras. We've also heard of the RgVedic **Brahman** the **Absolute** claimed to be the True **God** the **Almighty** who's **One** and only One. Evidently, the Devatas that fought and conquered the Asuras were Not the RgVedic Brahman the Absolute aka God the Almighty, the **Creator** of the Universe as well as all humans, plants & animals, Devatas, and Asuras. It sounds Ridiculous that God created Asuras & Devatas to fight & kill one another. Very mysterious are these Devatas aka gods. God is One, but ***gods*** seem to be ***numerous*** like humans, plants & animals. I'm curious to know the ***exact*** number of the **RgVedic** gods.

Comment: duplicate question.